Spawner waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available when they are already available
ros2 launch autonomous_bot launch_robot.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/rushabh/.ros/log/2024-04-18-14-09-33-038824-rushabh-Aspire-A515-57G-11932
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [11934]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713429573.221321794] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713429573.221443136] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713429573.221450083] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713429573.221454462] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713429573.221458020] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713429573.221461770] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713429573.221465416] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process started with pid [11969]
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process started with pid [11971]
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process started with pid [11973]
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713429577.313543564] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713429577.314012686] [controller_manager]: update rate is 50 Hz
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713429577.314141952] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1713429579.557576828] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1713429579.557659421] [spawner_joint_board]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1713429581.577298020] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1713429581.579662994] [spawner_joint_board]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available

Launch File:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, TimerAction
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import Command
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart

from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():



    package_name='autonomous_bot' #<--- CHANGE ME

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'false','use_ros2_control': 'true'}.items()
    )

    robot_description = Command(['ros2 param get --hide-type /robot_state_publisher robot_description'])

    controller_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','my_controller.yaml')

    controller_manager = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[{'robot_state_publisher': robot_description},
                    controller_params_file]
    )

    delayed_controller_manager = TimerAction(period=3.0, actions=[controller_manager])

    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["diff_cont"],
    )

    delayed_diff_drive_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[diff_drive_spawner],
        )
    )

    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_board"],
    )

    delayed_joint_broad_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[joint_broad_spawner],
        )
    )
    
    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,    
        delayed_controller_manager,
        delayed_diff_drive_spawner,
        delayed_joint_broad_spawner
    ])

Updated Lunch File:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, TimerAction
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import Command , FindExecutable, PathJoinSubstitution, LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart

from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():

    package_name='autonomous_bot' #<--- CHANGE ME

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'false','use_ros2_control': 'true'}.items()
    )

    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare("autonomous_bot"), "description", "robot.urdf.xacro"]
            )
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}
    
    
    robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("autonomous_bot"),
            "config",
            "my_controller.yaml",
        ]
    )
    
    controller_manager = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[{'robot_publisher': robot_description},
                    robot_controllers],
        output="both",
        remappings=[
            ("~/robot_description", "/robot_description"),
        ],
    )
    delayed_controller_manager = TimerAction(period=3.0, actions=[controller_manager])

    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        name="diff_drive_node",
        arguments=["diff_cont","--controller-manager","/controller_manager"],
    )


    delayed_diff_drive_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[diff_drive_spawner],
        )
    )

    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        name="joint_board_node",
        arguments=["joint_board", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    delayed_joint_broad_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[joint_broad_spawner],
        )
    )
    
    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,    
        delayed_controller_manager,
        delayed_diff_drive_spawner,
        delayed_joint_broad_spawner
    ])

Waiting For controller_manager
ros2 launch autonomous_bot launch_robot.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/rushabh/.ros/log/2024-04-20-15-15-32-490651-rushabh-Aspire-A515-57G-100094
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [100096]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713606332.670566684] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713606332.670633728] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713606332.670640275] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713606332.670644199] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713606332.670647728] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713606332.670651107] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713606332.670654407] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process started with pid [100107]
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process started with pid [100109]
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process started with pid [100111]
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713606335.766524402] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '~/robot_description' topic for robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713606335.767870090] [controller_manager]: update rate is 50 Hz
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713606335.768096350] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713606335.770032588] [controller_manager]: Received robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713606335.770931780] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'RealRobot' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [ERROR] [1713606335.772507756] [controller_manager]: The published robot description file (urdf) seems not to be genuine. The following error was caught:According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduinoHardware with base class type hardware_interface::SystemInterface does not exist. Declared types are  diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduino fake_components/GenericSystem fake_robot/FakeRobot mock_components/GenericSystem ros2_control_demo_example_1/RRBotSystemPositionOnlyHardware ros2_control_demo_example_10/RRBotSystemWithGPIOHardware ros2_control_demo_example_11/CarlikeBotSystemHardware ros2_control_demo_example_12/RRBotSystemPositionOnlyHardware ros2_control_demo_example_2/DiffBotSystemHardware ros2_control_demo_example_3/RRBotSystemMultiInterfaceHardware ros2_control_demo_example_4/RRBotSystemWithSensorHardware ros2_control_demo_example_5/RRBotSystemPositionOnlyHardware ros2_control_demo_example_7/RobotSystem ros2_control_demo_example_8/RRBotTransmissionsSystemPositionOnlyHardware ros2_control_demo_example_9/RRBotSystemPositionOnlyHardware test_hardware_components/TestSystemCommandModes test_hardware_components/TestTwoJointSystem test_system test_unitilizable_system
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1713606338.006259514] [joint_board_node]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1713606338.033747887] [diff_drive_node]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1713606340.025236425] [joint_board_node]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1713606340.055888924] [diff_drive_node]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1713606342.043060206] [joint_board_node]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1713606342.073341265] [diff_drive_node]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713606343.637814415] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713606343.637832946] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[spawner-4] Traceback (most recent call last):
[spawner-4]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 33, in <module>
[spawner-4]     sys.exit(load_entry_point('controller-manager==2.40.0', 'console_scripts', 'spawner')())
[spawner-4]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 222, in main
[spawner-4]     if not wait_for_controller_manager(
[spawner-4]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 117, in wait_for_controller_manager
[spawner-4]     return wait_for_value_or(
[spawner-4]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 66, in wait_for_value_or
[spawner-4]     time.sleep(0.2)
[spawner-4] KeyboardInterrupt
[spawner-3] Traceback (most recent call last):
[spawner-3]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 33, in <module>
[spawner-3]     sys.exit(load_entry_point('controller-manager==2.40.0', 'console_scripts', 'spawner')())
[spawner-3]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 222, in main
[spawner-3]     if not wait_for_controller_manager(
[spawner-3]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 117, in wait_for_controller_manager
[spawner-3]     return wait_for_value_or(
[spawner-3]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 66, in wait_for_value_or
[spawner-3]     time.sleep(0.2)
[spawner-3] KeyboardInterrupt
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 100096]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 100107]
[ERROR] [spawner-3]: process has died [pid 100109, exit code -2, cmd '/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_board --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=joint_board_node'].
[ERROR] [spawner-4]: process has died [pid 100111, exit code -2, cmd '/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner diff_cont --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=diff_drive_node'].

Updated Error:
ros2 launch autonomous_bot launch_robot.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/rushabh/.ros/log/2024-04-20-16-37-28-158366-rushabh-Aspire-A515-57G-7522
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [7525]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713611248.348936923] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713611248.348996005] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713611248.349001512] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713611248.349004790] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713611248.349007612] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713611248.349010361] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713611248.349013077] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process started with pid [7538]
[INFO] [spawner-3]: process started with pid [7540]
[INFO] [spawner-4]: process started with pid [7542]
[ros2_control_node-2] [WARN] [1713611251.557724221] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713611251.558355130] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'RealRobot' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713611251.560909233] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'RealRobot' 
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1713611251.561054032] [DiffDriveArduino]: Configuring...
[ros2_control_node-2] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
[ros2_control_node-2]   what():  stoi
[ros2_control_node-2] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[ros2_control_node-2] #30   Object "", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[ros2_control_node-2] #29   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a65864, in _start
[ros2_control_node-2] #28   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x781b5ce29e3f]
[ros2_control_node-2] #27   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in __libc_start_call_main [0x781b5ce29d8f]
[ros2_control_node-2] #26   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a6623c, in main
[ros2_control_node-2] #25   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a68076, in std::shared_ptr<controller_manager::ControllerManager> std::make_shared<controller_manager::ControllerManager, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #24   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a68cdc, in std::shared_ptr<controller_manager::ControllerManager> std::allocate_shared<controller_manager::ControllerManager, std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager>, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager> const&, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #23   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a69594, in std::shared_ptr<controller_manager::ControllerManager>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager>, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager> >, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #22   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a69ab5, in std::__shared_ptr<controller_manager::ControllerManager, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager>, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager> >, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #21   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a69da0, in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<controller_manager::ControllerManager, std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager>, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(controller_manager::ControllerManager*&, std::_Sp_alloc_shared_tag<std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager> >, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #20   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a6a3ea, in std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<controller_manager::ControllerManager, std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager>, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #19   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a6a7e3, in void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager> >::construct<controller_manager::ControllerManager, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(std::allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager>&, controller_manager::ControllerManager*, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #18   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x636237a6acc7, in void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<controller_manager::ControllerManager>::construct<controller_manager::ControllerManager, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(controller_manager::ControllerManager*, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #17   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x781b5de743e6, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::ControllerManager(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::NodeOptions const&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #16   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x781b5de763eb, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::init_resource_manager(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #15   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/hardware_interface/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x781b5cd6d08e, in hardware_interface::ResourceManager::load_urdf(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool)
[ros2_control_node-2] #14   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/hardware_interface/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x781b5cd77738, in hardware_interface::ResourceStorage::load_and_initialize_system(hardware_interface::HardwareInfo const&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #13   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/hardware_interface/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x781b5cd77530, in auto hardware_interface::ResourceStorage::load_and_initialize_system(hardware_interface::HardwareInfo const&)::{lambda(auto:1&)#1}::operator()<std::vector<hardware_interface::System, std::allocator<hardware_interface::System> > >(std::vector<hardware_interface::System, std::allocator<hardware_interface::System> >&) const
[ros2_control_node-2] #12   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/hardware_interface/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x781b5cd7d4b9, in bool hardware_interface::ResourceStorage::initialize_hardware<hardware_interface::System>(hardware_interface::HardwareInfo const&, hardware_interface::System&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #11   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/hardware_interface/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x781b5cdb547e, in hardware_interface::System::initialize(hardware_interface::HardwareInfo const&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #10   Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/diffdrive_arduino/lib/libdiffdrive_arduino.so", at 0x781b58687252, in diffdrive_arduino::DiffDriveArduino::on_init(hardware_interface::HardwareInfo const&)
[ros2_control_node-2] #9    Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/hardware_interface/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x781b5cd3749c, in std::__cxx11::stoi(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long*, int)
[ros2_control_node-2] #8    Object "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/hardware_interface/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x781b5cd39403, in int __gnu_cxx::__stoa<long, int, char, int>(long (*)(char const*, char**, int), char const*, char const*, unsigned long*, int)
[ros2_control_node-2] #7    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x781b5d2a53f1, in std::__throw_invalid_argument(char const*)
[ros2_control_node-2] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x781b5d2ae4d7, in __cxa_throw
[ros2_control_node-2] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x781b5d2ae276, in std::terminate()
[ros2_control_node-2] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x781b5d2ae20b, in 
[ros2_control_node-2] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.30", at 0x781b5d2a2b9d, in 
[ros2_control_node-2] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x781b5ce287f2]
[ros2_control_node-2] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x781b5ce42475]
[ros2_control_node-2] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[ros2_control_node-2]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[ros2_control_node-2]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x781b5ce969fc]
[ros2_control_node-2] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 7538 1000)
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-2]: process has died [pid 7538, exit code -6, cmd '/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_zo48ua28 --params-file /home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/autonomous_bot/share/autonomous_bot/config/my_controller.yaml -r ~/robot_description:=/robot_description'].
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1713611253.804555847] [joint_board_node]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-4] [INFO] [1713611253.804763676] [diff_drive_node]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1713611255.415405446] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[spawner-4] Traceback (most recent call last):
[spawner-4]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 33, in <module>
[spawner-4]     sys.exit(load_entry_point('controller-manager==2.40.0', 'console_scripts', 'spawner')())
[spawner-4]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 222, in main
[spawner-4]     if not wait_for_controller_manager(
[spawner-4]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 106, in wait_for_controller_manager
[spawner-4]     node_and_namespace = wait_for_value_or(
[spawner-4]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 66, in wait_for_value_or
[spawner-4]     time.sleep(0.2)
[spawner-4] KeyboardInterrupt
[spawner-3] Traceback (most recent call last):
[spawner-3]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner", line 33, in <module>
[spawner-3]     sys.exit(load_entry_point('controller-manager==2.40.0', 'console_scripts', 'spawner')())
[spawner-3]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 222, in main
[spawner-3]     if not wait_for_controller_manager(
[spawner-3]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 106, in wait_for_controller_manager
[spawner-3]     node_and_namespace = wait_for_value_or(
[spawner-3]   File "/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/controller_manager/spawner.py", line 66, in wait_for_value_or
[spawner-3]     time.sleep(0.2)
[spawner-3] KeyboardInterrupt
[ERROR] [spawner-3]: process has died [pid 7540, exit code -2, cmd '/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_board --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=joint_board_node'].
[ERROR] [spawner-4]: process has died [pid 7542, exit code -2, cmd '/home/rushabh/ros2_ws/install/controller_manager/lib/controller_manager/spawner diff_cont --controller-manager /controller_manager --ros-args -r __node:=diff_drive_node'].


I think the problem is not specifying the controller manager, try:
    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        name="diff_drive_node",
        arguments=["diff_cont", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
    )

and
    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        name="joint_board_node",
        arguments=["joint_board", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

Both "-c" and "--controller-manager" should do the same work
...
In your "controller_params_file" file you should have the structure as:
controller_manager:
  joint_broad:
    type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
  diff_cont:
    type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController



Which version of ROS 2 are you using, and which version of ros2_control?
If you are using humble or iron:
You can either remap /controller_manager/robot_description to the correct topic of robot_state_publisher, then you should get something like

[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1713474775.815042617]
[controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.

or you can set the correct parameter (robot_description instead of robot_state_publisher):
 controller_manager = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description},
                    controller_params_file]
    )


I am using Humble above answer is giving me two errors:
[ros2_control_node-2] [WARN] [1713503893.142307756] [controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.

this is not an error, this is a warning. and what is the second "error"?

Same waiting for controller  Manager services

can you please compile and launch one of the official demos, e.g., example_1. Then you can compare it to your code and see where is the problem.

I already did that compared with example 2 (diff_Bot)

I have added updated launch file after comparison

did example_2 run on your setup?
From your updated file, remove robot_publisher parameter as this doesn't exist.

you have update also the console log, where the controller_manager initializes but the ressource manager fails. See the mismatch of the type names diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduinoHardware vs diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduino

Added Update Error Please Check

This seems to be an error with your hardware component or its parameter from the URDF (stoi throws an error)
